# How to bring firebug inspector in JS Fiddle Output window in Chrome Browser

Tags: javascript, firebug, jsfiddle

I come across a JSfiddle someone has posted in stack overflow automatically opened the firebug console only in the output window of JSFiddle. Does some one know how to achieve that.I guess they used the following link in the managed resources.

It works in Firefox on just adding it in managed resources.

I want this to be working in Chrome. I am using Chrome 19.0 with Firebug Extension

Thanks

https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite.js

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Just paste that URL in the box under Managed Resources that says 'JavaScript/CSS URL', click the plus-sign button and then click 'Run'. You should see firebug lite show up in the results window.

EDIT: This version seems to work in Chrome: https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite-debug.js

Comment: hmm - works for me in ff 10.0.2 - what browser/version are you using?

Comment: Modified the question with the browser specification

Comment: @MikeC : +1 Thanks Awesome, i was looking that from long time. :)

Answer (score 9):

in Frameworks & Extensions choose jQuery 1.x (edge) then underneath, choose firebug lite, That's it

Comment: Not only is this the simplest solution, it makes the most sense. Should be the selected answer IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Even its a out-dated, you can try the below jsFiddle:

## [jsFiddle with Firebug](http://jsfiddle.net/soundar24/nhdvqbsx/)

In your application itself you can add the below script in the head section, to embed the firebug:

```
<script src="https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite-debug.js"></script>
```